# if o(a) is equal to exponent of finite abelian group G then $G=<a>\times K$

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

problem:prove that if $o(a)$ is equal to the exponent of a finite Abelian group $G$, then there exists $H<G$ such that $G=H\times\langle a\rangle$$$$$
using fundamental theorem of finitely generated Abelian group we can assume $G=<x_1>\times...\times<x_n>$ if $a=a_1x_1+...+a_nx_n$ and $b=(a_1,...,a_n,o(a))=1$(because (o(a)/b)a=1) so we can extend a to a set of generators. so there is $H<G$ such that $G=H<a>$ I cant go further.any idea?

Comment: what is meant by exponent of finite group?

Comment: smallest n such that $g^n=e$ for every element of G

Comment: You could choose $h\in G\setminus \langle a\rangle$ of minimal order (with respect to not being power of $a$), show that it has prime order and use induction by looking at $G/\langle h\rangle$.

Comment: how can i use induction ? yes $G/<h>=<a,h>/<h>\times H/<h>$ but $G=<a>H$ and $<a>\cap H\subset <h>$ why $<a>\cap <h>=e$@j.p

Comment: oh!because the order of $h$ is prime!thanks@j.p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use [the structure theorems for finite abelian groups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finitely-generated_abelian_group#Classification), then it is easy:

- In the invariant factor decomposition, the largest factor has order equal to the exponent of $G$. Any $a\in G$ whose order is the exponent of $G$ must be a generator of this factor.
- If you want to start with the primary decomposition, then the Chinese remainder theorem allows us to reassemble the primary factors into an invariant factor decomposition.

If you cannot use the structure theorems, see
the book [*The Theory of Finite Groups: An Introduction*](http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2Fb97433), by Kurzweil and Stellmacher, which includes a proof of what you want in [Chapter 2](http://www.springer.com/cda/content/document/cda_downloaddocument/9780387405100-c1.pdf?SGWID=0-0-45-107321-p14004925), as a stepping stone to the structure theorems.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/q/792528/589.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1278685/589.