# There is an element, whose order is the exponent of $H$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification

> If $H$ is a subgroup of $K^*$, where $K$ is an arbitrary field, then there is an element $h\in H$, whose order is the exponent of $H$, that is the least common multiple of the elements of $H$

I think $K^*$ is the set of nonzero elements of $K$, So if the claim is not true then can I assume then the orders of the elements are relatively prime and then consider the product of the elements of $H$ without their inverse (if some element is self-inverse it doesn't matter it appears only once in the product), and then this product has the desired order, which is a contradicton, hence an element with such an order must exist ?

Is my proof OK

Comment: This is true for every finite abelian group: an element whose order is maximal has order equal to the exponent of the group. But I guess you're allowing $H$  to be infinite (which it can't be because it's inside a field).

Comment: The proof is much too imprecise.  What does "the product of the elements of $H$ without their inverse" mean for example? It would not get many marks in an exam.

Comment: @Derek Holt How can I improve it, Is it OK to say that; pick only one element of order $n$, so we can avoid inverses, since any element and its inverse have the same order

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two general facts here:

> If $H$ is a subgroup of the multiplicative group of a field $K$ and $H$ has finite exponent, then $H$ is finite.

Indeed, if $m$ is the exponent of $H$, then $x^m=1$ for all $x \in H$. Since $K$ is a field, this equation can only have a finite number of solutions.

> If $H$ is a finite abelian group and $m$ is the exponent of $H$, then there is an element in $H$ of order $m$.

Let $a \in H$ be an element of maximal order $n$. We will prove that $h^n=1$ for all $h \in H$. It will then follow that $n=m$.

Let $h \in H$ have order $t$. If $p$ is a prime divisor of $t$ that does not divide $n$, then $ah^{t/p}$ would have order $np > n$. Hence, all prime divisors of $t$ divide $n$. Write $n=p^e r$ and $t=p^f s$, with $(p,r)=1=(p,s)$. Then $a^{p^e} t^s$ has order $p^f r$ and so $p^f r \le n=p^e r$, which implies $f \le e$. Since this holds for all primes $p$ dividing $n$, we conclude that the orders of all elements of $H$ divide $n$.

Comment: @Ihf Thank you very much, I think you meant in the 2nd last line $r\le n=p^e\color{red}{r}$, and as all prime divisors of $t$ divide $n\implies s\mid r$, right ?

Comment: @ketum, yes, thanks, fixed. And I meant $v_p(t) \le v_p(n)$ for all $p$ means that $t \mid n$.

Comment: One could also mention that a finite subgroup of the multiplicative group of a field is always cyclic.

Comment: @user59363, indeed and that'd be a much faster path to the result. But somehow the statement given by the OP does not point to that direction.

Answer (score 1):

The statement is not true in general, see e.g. the Prüfer group (for some fixed prime $p$) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%BCfer_group as a subgroup  of $\mathbb{C}^*$, or any infinite subfield of $\overline{{\mathbb F}_p}$ (the algebraic closure of the $p$-element field). However, the statement is true for finite fields $K$.

Your "proof" is confusing --- which elements do you assume to have co-prime orders? I cannot really follow here. A look a the Prüfer group shows that the order of every non trivial element is divisible by $p$