# Order of a Group Based on Their Exponents

Tags: finite-groups

> Let $G$ be a finite commutative group. The exponent of $G$ is the least common multiple of all orders of all the elements of $G$. Show that $G$ has an element whose order equals the exponent of $G$.

Here is the question that I have been stuck on for the past 2 days. I haven't been able to come up with anything *useful* that would help show this result is true. Even my two good math friends, through a collaborative effort, weren't able to figure this question out... What do the orders of $G$ have to do with the least common multiple of the exponent of $G$?

Comment: Could you give us any specifics of what you tried?

Comment: Rough Sketch: Since we are given that $G$ is a finite commutative group, then this means that $G$ is abelian. Suppose that I have a commutative group G such that $G = a,b,c...,$, where Id $\in G$. Here, $Id$ stands for the identity element, since this is what is required of a commutative group. So the order of the elements of $G$ is the smallest positive integer, say $k$, such that for an element $a$, $a^k = Id$. That is as far as I got.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I think I finally got it. There may be some things for you to fill in, depending on how much you know, but here's an outline.

Suppose $|G|=p_1^{n_1}\ldots p_k^{n_k}$, then there exists subgroups $P_1,\ldots,P_k$ each of order $p_i^{n_i}$ (Sylow subgroups), and furthermore $G=P_1\times\ldots\times P_k$. Now for each $i$ take an element $g_i\in P_i$ with the highest order $p_i^{m_i}$, then we claim that the element $g_0=g_1\ldots g_k$ has order $p_1^{m_1}\ldots p_k^{m_k}=\text{lcm}(|G|)$.

Comment: Could you please say, for which $e$ is a group having exponent $e$ necessarily Abelian?

Answer (score 1):

let $f$ be an element of maximal order $m$ in the abelian group $G$ and let $e$ be the exponent of $G$. Then $m|e$. If $m$ is strictly less than $e$ there must be another element $g$ of order $n$ with LCM$(m,n) \gt m$ but now the order of $fg$ is LCM$(m,n)$ contradicting the assumption that $f$ has maximal order.

Comment: The order of $fg$ is not necessarily the lcm of $m$ and $n$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an argument that reduces the problem to when the exponent is a prime power.

Let $e$ be the exponent of $G$. If $e=ab$ with $\gcd(a,b)=1$ and $a,b >1$, let $A=\{ g \in G : g^a = 1 \}$ and $B=\{ g \in G : g^b = 1 \}$. Then by induction you have elements $\alpha \in A$ of order $a$ and $\beta \in B$ of order $b$. Then $\alpha \beta$ has order $ab=e$.

Comment: See also [Chapter 2](http://www.springer.com/cda/content/document/cda_downloaddocument/9780387405100-c1.pdf?SGWID=0-0-45-107321-p14004925) of the book [*The Theory of Finite Groups: An Introduction*](http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2Fb97433), by Kurzweil and Stellmacher, and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/792528/simple-proof-of-the-structure-theorems-for-finite-abelian-groups.

Comment: I will take a look at the textbook link.